# Pass parameter value in routes?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In my controller I have a delete method:

```
delete(String id, boolean confirmed)
```

Now in the routes I want to map two URIs accordingly:

```
GET /item/:id/delete           controllers.Application.delete(id:String, false)
GET /item/:id/delete/confirmed controllers.Application.delete(id:String, true)
```

(interesting part is the second parameter passed to the delete method depending on the URI)

This however gives me the following error:

```
 identifier expected but 'false' found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
GET /item/:id/delete           controllers.Application.delete(id:String, confirmed:Boolean ?= false)
GET /item/:id/delete/confirmed controllers.Application.delete(id:String, confirmed:Boolean ?= true)
```

Comment: What about /item/:id/delete?confirmed=true. Which action will be called?

Comment: The first one @andrey.ladniy

Comment: @biesior you are a lifesaver for so many play developers! Kudos!!